# How do I solve this problem related to Lagrangian?

Tags: conic-sections, lagrange-multiplier

I have a math assignment due this week and I really need help. I dont really understand the professor in class because he uses big words and explains in a very complex manner.

The question is:

The cylinder $x^2 + y^2 = 8$ intersects the plane $x + y + z = 1$ to form an ellipse.

i) Construct the Lagrangian, L, for finding the maximum and minimum values of $f(x, y, z) = 4 - z$ on the ellipse.

ii) Find the stationary points for L.

iii) Hence, find the maximum and minimum values of $f(x, y, z)$.

I hope someone can help me because I am really so lost.

Comment: Intersection of plane and cylinder is the constraint whose equation you need to find as $g(x,y,z)$  in its parametric form. The function to be extremized is simply $4-z$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $L(x,y,z, \lambda, \mu)=4-z+\lambda(x^2+y^2-8)+ \mu(x+y+z-1)$.

For the stationary points of $L$ you have to solve the system

$2 \lambda x+\mu=0$,

$2 \lambda y+\mu=0$,

$-1+\mu=0$,

$x^2+y^2=8$,

$x+y+z=1$.

Your turn !

Comment: thank you so much!

Comment: hi how do i present my answer once i have solved it?